# How to solve EER Diagram Visual Error in Worbench and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image]

Hi friends, I am on Ubuntu 20.04 But my Worbench it is not working fine, the EER image is damaged and the objects do not open as seen in the attached image. It looks like a memory problem but my PC is 32GB

Comment: Which version of MySQL Workbench is that? The problem you see is just cosmetic and, while annoying, not critical.Close and reopen the tab to get rid of that. And which objects did you try to open? In the image I see you have the layer object editor open, so it seems as if that part would work.

Comment: Hi Myke, I really appreciate your answer. My MySql Workbench version 8.0.23. the first quarter of the screen can be seen well but does not allow to work either

Comment: Hi Eltom4, what if you close the left bar? Is that help? Can you upload wb log to see if we can spot there some clue? I tried reproduced issue on my machine, but I can't.

Comment: Hi Myke, sorry for the delay. I see that the design problem is because my monitor is 4K and I use to scale to 200%. So when I returned to 100% the problem was solved. Thanks for your help. It is a bug on this versión of Ubuntu 20.04 an Workbench because in ubuntu 18.04 worked ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MySQL-Workbench v8.0.30 on Ubuntu 22.04, I experienced the same problem.

The Original Poster Eltom4 provided the solution in their comment.

I don't have enough reputation to comment above
and the question is without an accepted answer.

I wanted to confirm that the fix suggested by Eltom4 worked for me.

You must set 'scaling' to 100% on a 4k or HiDPI monitor.

[image: Picture of display settings in Ubuntu. Scaling is set to 100%]

After making this change, MySQL-Workbench looked and functioned correctly.

Comment: Make sure also the fractional scaling is disabled (even if you set 100% on scaling).